# Javascript modification of CSS class url change for background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I am trying to get a background image to change based on a setting in the database, for right now I'm just trying to get a a way of simply modifying the image used without using the data base but I'm hitting a snag. Without the javascript the image appears fine, with the javascript it is simply not there; leading me to believe there is an issue finding the path written to the css.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function changecss(myclass, element) {
        var CSSRules
        var link1 = "url('../../graphics/MainMenuBG0.gif')";
        var link2 = "url('../../graphics/MainMenuBG1.gif')";
        if (document.all) {
            CSSRules = 'rules';
        }
        else if (document.getElementById) {
            CSSRules = 'cssRules';
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets[0][CSSRules].length; i++) {
            if (document.styleSheets[0][CSSRules][i].selectorText == myclass) {
                if (document.styleSheets[0][CSSRules][i].style[element] == link1) {
                    document.styleSheets[0][CSSRules][i].style[element] = link2;
                } else {
                    document.styleSheets[0][CSSRules][i].style[element] = link1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to give your question a much higher probability of being answered I would suggest putting together a *working* sample using jsfiddle.net or the like.

Comment: What's contained within the `element` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this :

```
if (document.styleSheets[0][CSSRules][i].style.getProperty('background-image') == link1) {
    document.styleSheets[0][CSSRules][i].style.setProperty('background-image', link2);
} else {
    document.styleSheets[0][CSSRules][i].style.setProperty('background-image', link1);
}
```